# Rewrite in the form $ab^t$: $(5^{-2t}) \cdot 4^t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I think $a=1$ and $b=4/25$ but am not sure. I simplified $5^{-2t}$ to $1/5^{2t}$ and then to $1/(5^2)^t$ to get $1/25^t$.

Answer (score 1):

$$5^{-2t} \cdot 4^t
= \frac{4^t}{5^{2t}}
= \frac{4^t}{(5^2)^t}
= \left( \frac{4}{25} \right)^t
$$

- First equality follows by the rule $a^{-b} = 1/a^b$
- Second equality follows by the rule $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$
- Third equality follows by the rule $(a/b)^c = a^c/b^c$ (and that $5^2=25$)

Hence, yes, you wish to choose $a=1$ and $b=4/25$.

Comment: Thank you! :)  .

Comment: @JamesonBast If this answered your question to your satisfaction, please consider marking it with the green tick.